# JavaScript: Who decides on client-side APIs?

Tags: javascript

Quick and simple question, just wondering!

Core language is defined by **ECMA** and implemented by browsers. But who decides on the environment's(browsers) features? for example

Can Google add a new method to Chrome for grabbing a special kind of node while others don't have it?

sorry if this is silly.

Comment: Each browser implements the standards, but they can implement whatever else they want.  No central person decides this.  Someone at Google decides they want to add a widget, and they do if it doesn't break any specs.

Comment: Google tests out new features all the time. Put `chrome://flags` in the address bar to see some.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about things like `document.getElementById`, such that a browser might want to implement `document.getSomeNewSpecialNode`, then it's the [World Wide Web Consortium (W3C)](https://www.w3.org/).

> The World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) is an international community that develops open standards to ensure the long-term growth of the Web.

Individual browsers can (and often do) add features to their own browsers, sometimes these gain the support of the W3 and thus become standardised, but this process can take a long time.

---

Other than the core standards, browsers can of course implement any other features they like, whether they're bookmark bars or plugins etc, without adhering to any central specification - this is an area where the browsers can more freely compete on features.

Comment: I'm curious why this was downvoted. Here, have my upvote.

Comment: Me too, but don't feel you need to give out pity-upvotes :)

Comment: I asked because of **attachevent** and **addeventlistener**.  Whoever gives a feature first, others should copy it's name? ha?

Comment: I upvoted because the answer is good.

Comment: @Meysam `attachevent` is an example of a browser not following the standard and going their own way and thus causing problems for web developers.  IE finally works with `addeventlistener` now.

Comment: @Meysam In the 90's, the early days of the web, it was a bit of the wild west, and Microsoft was a big fish in a small pond. They thought that they could do whatever they wanted and everyone else would follow. Standards slowly emerged and slowly turned the tables.